# MySql Subqueries not returning a result

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get my project to work remotely. I have everything working perfectly on my local machine but on my remote machine some of my webpages are not displaying the results from certain servlets. I know this is the case because my callback function is never called in the front end which means something is wrong with the back end.

This only occurs when my servlets are sending queries that have subqueries contained in them. I know that this is the case from checking the mysql logs. My servlet is trying to send two queries that have subqueries in them but when I check the `mysql` log it only received the first subquery.
 The second query is never recorded in the logs. I then tried to see if I can manually run queries with subqueries in mysql via the terminal. I tried queries such as

1)

```
SELECT stars.id, stars.name 
FROM stars 
WHERE stars.id IN (SELECT stars_in_movies.starId FROM stars_in_movies, movies WHERE movies.id = 'tt0145487' AND stars_in_movies.movieId = movies.id)
```

Even simpler ones such as

2)

```
SELECT movies.title 
FROM movies 
WHERE movies.title in (select movies.title from movies where movies.title = 'Spider-Man').
```

In both cases I am not receiving a result from MySql. I am running these queries on Ubuntu.

Comment: Can't understand the second query? Why are you using sub-query it can be achieve with single query... Select movies.* from movies where  movies.title = 'Spider-Man'

Comment: I was just trying to come up with a query with a subquery to test if mysql can even run queries with subqueries. I know that the second subquery is redundant.

Comment: Read about JOINS

Comment: Execute the subqueries stand-alone. Do you get any result?

Comment: What happens when you run `SELECT 1+1` via the terminal?

Comment: Maybe you do not have such matching records in your database

Comment: Addressing the questions.
jarlh -> The subqueries do produce a result.
Vatev ->  Select 1+1 returns 2. 
Mittal -> I have the matching records in the database.

Comment: After doing some more testing I found out that the queries that I was trying to use were extremely costly. Writing the equivalent query using joins solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just use joins.

```
SELECT A.id, A.name 
FROM stars A JOIN stars_in_movies B 
ON A.id=B.starId AND B.movieId = 'tt0145487';
```

Comment: Shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: At least there's no subqueries used here!